# Spark - How to get the Singleton instance of HiveContext?

Tags: singleton, apache-spark-sql

How do i create a `Singleton instance` of `HiveContext`?

In `SQLContext`, we have a method called `getOrCreate` to create a singleton instance of SQLContext. But i don't see same kind of method in HiveContext.

**Update:** We are using Spark 1.6.1, so we cannot use 2.0 SparkSession.

Answer (score 1):

HiveContext and SqlContext is getting combined.It deprecate HiveContext in Spark2.0
Refer :
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13737